# Heroku remote won't delete

Tags: heroku, command-line

I need to remove an existing Heroku remote. I've done this before, but it just doesn't seem to be working this time around. I've searched for options, and tried solutions from other posts, but I feel like I'm going in circles. Here's what I have:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:radiant-journey-2028.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:radiant-journey-2028.git (push)
```

I've tried:

```
$ git rm -rf heroku
$ git rm -rf heroku remote
$ rm heroku remote
```

However, all I get is (or variations of these responses):

```
fatal: pathspec 'heroku' did not match any files
rm: heroku: No such file or directory
rm: remote: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I found the correct answer thirty seconds after I posted. If it helps anybody else, the correct command is: $ git remote rm heroku

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Removing a remote in git is achieved with the following command:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Comment: How would you do this with if there is more than one remote for one app?

Comment: Just the same. Other remotes have names different from `heroku`. You can list them all with `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote rm heroku
```

This is the correct format

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30569344)